# What about $GL(n,\mathbb C)$? Is it open, dense in $M(n,\mathbb C)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology

What about $GL(n,\mathbb C)$? Is it open, dense in $M(n,\mathbb C)$?

Comment: Yes, and yes.  This is a nice exercise.

Comment: Too bad the question is tagged topological vector spaces. I was going to say something about the Zariski topology (much as I loathe to think of it as a topology, at the moment).

Answer (score 31):

It seems like we agree that the openness of $\operatorname{GL}_n(\mathbb{C})$ is most easily proved by observing that it is the preimage of the open set $\mathbb{C} \setminus \{0\}$ under the continuous function $\operatorname{det}: M_n(\mathbb{C}) \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$.

We are giving different answers for the density, and I have not yet seen the simple linear algebra answer I was expecting to see.

Here it is: let $M \in M_n(\mathbb{C})$.  It is sufficient to show that there exists $\epsilon > 0$ such that for all nonzero complex numbers $t$ with $|t| < \epsilon$, the matrix 
$M + t I_n$ is nonsingular (because then $M$ is a limit point of this set of nonsingular matrices).  But viewing $t$ as an indeterminate, the determinant of $M+t I_n$ is nothing else than the characteristic polynomial $P(t)$ of $-M$.  Being a monic polynomial of degree $n$, it has $n$ roots $\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n$ (possibly with multiplicity), and we may take $\epsilon = \min_{i \ | \ \alpha_i \neq 0} |\alpha_i|$.

Note that this argument works verbatim for matrices over $\mathbb{R}$ or any nondiscrete normed field.  In fact, for an arbitrary field $k$, if one works instead with the Zariski topology on $M_n(k)$, then what we really need is for any cofinite subset of $k$ (i.e., the complement in $k$ of some finite set) to be dense in the Zariski topology.  This is true iff $k$ is infinite.  If $k$ is finite, the Zariski topology on $M_n(k)$ is discrete, and the result is false.

**Added**: A fun application of this "linear algebraic perturbation perspective" is to show that $\operatorname{GL}_n(\mathbb{C})$ is connected (whereas $\operatorname{GL}_n(\mathbb{R})$ is not).  Hint: by general nonsense, it is equivalent to show path-connectedness, so try that instead.  If I am trying to find a path from point $A$ to point $B$ in the complex plane, requiring that my path avoid a finite set of points is not nearly as problematic as it would be on the real line!

Comment: I'm pretty sure your "simple linear algebra" answer is what Jonas Meyer compressed into the last sentence of his answer :)

Comment: @Willie: I think you're right.  He threw me off by talking about Banach algebras.

Comment: I am having trouble in analyzing the denseness definition of Matrices. A subset $A \subset X$ is said to be dense in $X$ if for every $x \in X$, $B(x,r) \cap X \neq \emptyset$. How do you formulate this definition in terms of Matrices. Could you please elaborate.

Comment: @Chandru: $M_n$ is a finite dimensional vector space. Introduce a norm on it (doesn't matter which one, as topologically all norms on a finite dimensional vector space are equivalent). For any norm, you have that $\| tI_n\| = \| (M + t I_n) - M\| \sim t$. Now apply the first paragraph of Pete's proof.

Comment: @Willie: Thanks willie :)

Answer (score 9):

The amount of algebraic geometry needed to prove the denseness of $GL_n({\Bbb C})$ is indeed very minimal.

The topology of $M_n({\Bbb C})$ comes from its obvious identification with ${\Bbb C}^{n^2}$. The complement is the zero set of the determinant which is a polynomial in the $n^2$ entries of the matrix. The zero set of a polynomial cannot have inner points: if a polynomial vanishes on an open ball, its Taylor expansion centered at any point of the ball is identically 0, and by analicity the polynomial vanishes identically. Therefore there are no proper closed subsets of $M_n({\Bbb C})$ containing $GL_n({\Bbb C})$.

Comment: Since I suppose it is not possible to have a negative amount of algebraic geometry, I concur with the statement made in your first sentence.  (I.e., you certainly do not need any algebraic geometry at all in order to prove this.)

Comment: Nevertheless, I agree that if you know any algebraic geometry, it is very tempting to think about the problem in these terms.  (See my answer below.)

Answer (score 7):

Yes, it is both open and dense.  One way to show it is open is by considering the determinant.  Alternatively, the set of invertible elements of any Banach algebra is open (and $M(n,\mathbb{C})$ is a Banach algebra if you give it any submultiplicative norm), which follows from the fact that if $a$ is invertible and $\|a-b\|\lt \frac{1}{\|a^{-1}\|}$, then $b$ is invertible.  One way to show it is dense is to consider the fact that $a\in M(n,\mathbb{C})$ has only a finite set of eigenvalues.

Answer (score 4):

For the denseness part, one way to look at is this: A matrix is in $GL_n({\mathbb C})$ iff its rows are linearly independent over ${\mathbb C}$. So what you need to show is that given any matrix $M$ and an $\epsilon > 0$, you can perturb each entry by less than $\epsilon$ (in magnitude) and end out with linearly independent rows.

Or you can appeal to algebraic geometry and say that $det(M) = 0$ defines an algebraic variety which therefore has measure zero. But of course this is pretty advanced :)