# If $f\in C^1(\mathbb{R},M_n(\mathbb{R}))$ such that $f(0)=0$ and $f'(0)=I$, show that the image of f contains a regular matrix

Tags: analysis

If $f\in C^1(\mathbb{R},M_n(\mathbb{R}))$ such that $f(0)=0$ and $f'(0)=I$, show that the image of f contains a regular matrix.

While trying to prove something (elementary) from representation theory, I came to a stop. This fact would complete the proof. Can anyone prove it or find a counterexample? Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "regular" here?

Comment: @NateEldredge You supposed correctly, under "regular" I meant "invertible".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here I assume that "regular" means "invertible".

The fact that $f(0)=0$ and $f'(0)=I$ means that as $t \to 0$, $\frac{1}{t} f(t) \to I$.  [The set of invertible matrices is open](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/84392/why-do-the-n-times-n-non-singular-matrices-form-an-open-set) and of course contains $I$.  Therefore, for all sufficiently small nonzero $t$, $\frac{1}{t} f(t)$ is invertible, and thus so is $f(t)$.

Comment: Thank you very much! So simple, yet (to me) so elusive...