# derivative of matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, differential-topology

Is the nonsingular matrices open?

How can I show that every $m \times n$ matrix is in the image of the derivative of an $m \times n$ matrix (how to differentiate it?)

Thanks

Comment: Your first question is [answered here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/84392/264) (for the future, note that it is generally better to have one question per post, to keep things orderly).

Comment: This is true more generally in a unital Banach algebra, where we don't have the determinant to do that. The key, which works in any case, is that $I+A$ is invertible by the [Neumann series](http://planetmath.org/neumannseries) whenever $\|A\|<1$ for a submultiplicative norm. It follows that if $A$ is invertible, then so is $A+B$ whenever $\|B\|<\|A^{-1}\|^{-1}$.