# how can we prove that the subset of all invertible matrices is open?

Tags: matrices

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why do the $n \times n$ non-singular matrices form an “open” set?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/84392/why-do-the-n-times-n-non-singular-matrices-form-an-open-set)

Consider the space of all nxn matrices with real entries with the standard metric,
i.e.,view the matrix as an element of $R^{n^2} $and use the usual Euclidean metric on $R^{n^2} $. I need to prove that the subset of all invertible matrices is open. Please any idea?

Comment: Another related question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/18964/what-about-gln-mathbb-c-is-it-open-dense-in-mn-mathbb-c

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\bf Hint:$ $A$ is invertible iff the determinant is different from zero.